# How can I access the client machine folder in Azure Web API

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, webapi

Here I am trying to access the file from client machine on which running the Application using Azure web API. How can I access the client machine folders in Azure Web API Controller. Is it possible ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Think about the security implications of a remote web API being able to access the file system on a user's computer. Of course you cannot do that.